# App with different portions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am hoping that someone could help answer my question.

**Problem**
I am looking at developing an iOS application that compromises of smaller portions/functionalities (lets call it mini apps just for understanding better). I am looking for guidance on how I should approach this problem to ensure that there are no potential errors in the future. Just to give you a background of my problem, I will run through some of my approach.

**First Approach**
My initial approach was to develop and release a bunch of apps that can talk to one another. But since iOS apps can only inter-communicate with URLScheme, and which is not sufficient enough for me, I decided to revisit later and look for better solutions.

**Second Approach**
I also looked at making the apps have a common local database, but since iOS apps are restricted only to their sandbox, this again won't work.

**Third Approach**
The third approach was to have an app talk to a webService and back again to the other app.

**Current Approach**
So instead of having a bunch of apps installed on a device that can talk to one another, I am now looking at going with the approach of having only one master app that has different portions/functionalities.

My problem is figuring out how to properly manage my files that are specific to the different portions/functionalities/mini Apps, so that I could independently push a portion updated files to the app and not have it corrupt the other portions.

Would it be a good idea to create a subfolder in the app Document directory for the different portions of the app? Are the other approaches feasible?

I am looking for your help, approach and feedback in tackling the problem.

Thanks

Comment: It pretty hard to advise without knowing the entire context and scope. With "files" you mean data files that are stored on the device? Creating subdirectories in the Documents directory would essentially give each 'sub app' it's own documents location.

Comment: @Rengers thanks for the feedback. Yes data file that are to be stored in the device. I am now considering the first approach, but instead of using  the Url scheme to communicate between the apps, I am going to use the App groups capability for the suite of apps. I am looking to move my core data/sqlite db to the shared folder, there by making communication easy. What are your thoughts? Do you foresee any problems? security?

Comment: I have never worked with app groups so I can't advise on that specifically. One problem I foresee is multiple applications accessing/mutating the same storage at the same time. I don't know whether app groups allow this, but you might run into issues with that.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be an issue to deal with. Thanks